# Cluster in Azure [Debian 9, Corosync, Pacemaker, Slony-I]

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I want to setup a Debian9-based "Custom Application"-Cluster on Azure.

In OnPrem environments, the setup is actually quite simple:
Node 1, Node 2 + available and unused Virtual Database IP (same subnet)

Then the build starts and the cluster is ready for use in 5-10 minutes.

I did the same in azure, create a own vnet for the cluster nodes, installed both nodes and set an unused internal ip as virtual database ip and tried to start the cluster installation, this works fine for me. But after the installation the virtual database ip is not reachable.

**Example**

node1 - 10.10.10.01

node2 - 10.10.10.02
virtual ip (active on the primary node) - 10.10.10.03

Ping from node1 to 10.10.10.03

64 bytes from 10.10.10.03: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms

Ping from node2 to 10.10.10.02

From 10.10.10.03 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Is there maybe some advise you can give based on this information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use a second Network Interface Card instead of virtual ip? Azure Vnet is not always work well with static ip/routing or nat, as there are some internal services as well (DHCP, DNS, In-VM notification service etc.)

Comment: No yet, no. I think too that this is a vnet-configuration-problem, but im not familiar with azure. So I should create a 2nd network interface card and assign the ressources (VMs) to this one?

Comment: I am not familiar with your solution, but from my Azure experience I suggest to try to avoid any virtual IPs and static routing, and try just to add a second NIC to your VM

Answer (score 0):

All azure traffic for any resource goes through the gateway and the gateway directs it to the servers based on the IP address that Azure knows about. If you add additional IP addresses to the server, nothing else will be able to see them because they weren't added through Azure (which is essentially what the failover cluster has done).

The ARP request sent will not be received by the destination in Azure. The Gateway will intercept it and reply it with a fake MAC address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc. Then the sender will send the packet to gateway and the gateway will forward it to the sender. And if we add an additional IP address on the VM which is unknown to Azure, the gateway will not respond to an ARP request containing a unknown destination. So that the sender's ARP request will fail and the error message "Destination host unreachable" shows up.

Thus, additional IP addresses need to be added to the VM or node through Azure Powershell and not through the classic control panel deployment option in case of Azure as the Network Security group and virtual network configuration need to be modified as well.

Please refer to the below Microsoft documentation on how to add multiple IP addresses to resources: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell

Thanking you,